# How do I give an array a name that already exist (eg. for two different types of arrays)?

Tags: c++

I have two Data-type Array with same name, one is a string and the other is double, how do i target the double DT for cin.

```
string student[2] = {};
double student[2] = {0};
for(i = 0; i < CONS; i++)
{
    cout << "Studient" << i + 1 << " Exam"<< i + 1 << "Score : ";   
    cin >> student[i];
}
```

Comment: [It won't work](https://ideone.com/Vl9BxY). Having two variables with the same name in the same scope is not possible.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do it with slightly different names?

Comment: you don't, you're example shouldn't even compile (redefinition with different basic type) - but assuming you put the double version into a nested block you get 'hiding', where the inner-most definition hides the definition of the outer scope - there's not way to get to it then

Comment: just want to know if its valid

Comment: @ChrysUgwu Which your compiler has already sorted out...

Answer (score 5):

You don't. Either name them something different or use a `struct` to hold the related data:

```
string student_name[2] = {};
double student_score[2] = {0};

// or

struct student
{
   student() : name(""), score(0) {}
   string name;
   double score;
};

student students[2];
```